# Make two (or more) transforms on same element work together

Tags: css, css-transforms

How can I make these two work together? It seems like they are blocking/breaking each other/ or invoking only broken `transform3d`

HTML structure

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="one" style="transform:translate3d(0,0,0)"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="one" style="transform:translate3d(0,200px,0)"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="one" style="transform:translate3d(100px,100px,0)"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
<div class="div one"></div>
```

CSS styling

```
#container {
    -webkit-perspective:200px;
    -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    width:450px
}
.one {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    -webkit-transition:1s ease all;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.two {
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 100px, 0);
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transition:1s ease all;
    border:1px solid black
}
.one:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.div.one {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
   -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,400px,0);
}
.div.one:hover{
    -webkit-transform:scale3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Fiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/q44ssh7g/1/

Comment: A CSS property has a single value for any particular element, derived based on the cascade. One value "wins" and that value takes effect. `transform` is no different. There is no notion of combining multiple values from different levels in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using multiple transforms you should combine it into one, like so:

```
transform: translate3d(0,400px,0) scale3d(0,0,0);
```

Or else it will overwrite/block, as you say.

Comment: Remember to use the same approach in inline styling!